# crear un index.php con ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Quiero realizar un `index.php` con la ayuda de *AJAX*, donde mediante un input y un button , meta un  numero en el input y al darle al button se repita tantas veces ese numero en un div que tengo en la pagina.

Mando codigo

**index.php**

```
<div class="container" id="contenedor">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#botonAjax").on("click", function(){
                var nom = $("#nombre").val();


                $("#cargador").load(
                     "$nom",
                    {"nom" : nom }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" value=""/>


    <h1><button class="btn btn-info" id="botonAjax">Enviar</button></h1>
</div>
<div id="cargador">
</div>
<?php
   $nom = $_POST["nom"];
?>
```

//codigo correcto//
index.php

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Prueba PHP</title>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<?php
  // $nom = $_POST["nom"];
?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="contenedor">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#botonAjax").on("click", function(){
//dame lo que vale este input               
               var nom = $("#nombre").val();

//en cargador carga este php(y te paso estos parametros
                $("#cargador").load("gen.php",{"nom1" : nom});                  
            });
        });

    </script>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" value=""/>


    <h1><button class="btn btn-info" id="botonAjax">Enviar</button></h1>
</div>
<div id="cargador">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**gen.php**

```
<?php
    $nom=$_POST["nom1"];
    echo "<center>".$nom."<br/>";

    for($i=0;$i<$nom;$i++){
        echo "<center>"."<input type='text'/>"."<br/>";
        //$i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: perdon, quiza me he confundido al explicarlo, al dar al boton me tiene que crear tantos inputs con numero haya introducido

Comment: ya lo he conseguido,mando codigo por si alguien lo quiere, no me deja  mandarlo

Comment: la correccion la he colgado en el codigo de la pregunta,gracias de todos modos